# How to repeat a word letter by letter based on the length of other string?

Tags: python, loops

I need to repeat a word letter by letter using Python, comparing it to the size of another text.

For example:

```py
ex_text = 'I am an example test text' # 25 characters
ex_word = 'coding'
rep_word = ''
    
for i in ex_word:
    while len(rep_word) < len(ex_text):
        rep_word += i
    
print(rep_word)
```

I'm trying to print something like:

```py
codingcodingcodingcodingc
```

PS: Actually, it would be better if the output also consider the white spaces, like: `c od in gcoding codi ngco`.

Comment: So what is the current output of your program? Is it anything like what you want?

Comment: Do you intend `ex_word = coding` or `ex_word = "coding"`? What's the value of the `coding` variable if that's what you intend?

Comment: Correction:
ex_word = "coding"
And my current output is something like ccccccccccccccccccccccc (the first letter of the ex_word repeating the correct amount)
PS: actually it would be better if the output also consider the white spaces, like: c od in gcoding codi ngco

Comment: I would start with `for i in len(ex_text):` and later I would use `index = i % len(ex_word)` to select char from `"coding"` - `ex_word[index]`

Comment: Please update your question with your real code. What you have posted  won't produce the output you claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
ex_text = "I am an example test text" #25 characters
ex_word = "coding"
rep_word = ""

while len(rep_word) < len(ex_text):
    for i in ex_word:
        rep_word += i
        if len(rep_word) >= len(ex_text):
            break

print(rep_word)
```

Answer (score 5):

Divide the length of `ex_text` by the length of `ex_word` to get the number of repetitions. If they don't divide evenly, use a slice to get the extra characters from the next repetition.

```
multiples, remainder = divmod(len(ex_test), len(ex_word))
rep_word = ex_word * multiples + ex_word[:remainder]
```

Comment: Very elegant solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a generator that produces the letters you want to repeat:

```
def coding():
    while True:
        for l in "coding":
            yield(l)

print("".join(list(c for (_, c) in zip("I am an example test text", coding()))))
```

displays: 'codingcodingcodingcodingc'

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `range(len(ex_text))` and use modulo `len(ex_word)` to get index of char in `ex_word`

```
ex_text = "I am an example test text" #25 characters''
ex_word = "coding"
rep_word = ""

for i in range(len(ex_text)):
    index = i % len(ex_word)   # modulo
    rep_word += ex_word[index]

print(rep_word)
```

Result

```
codingcodingcodingcodingc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ex_text = "I am an example test text"

ex_word = 'coding'
rep_word = ""

while len(ex_text)>len(rep_word):
    rep_word+=ex_word
while len(ex_text)!=len(rep_word):
    rep_word = rep_word[:-1]

print(rep_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```py
from itertools import cycle


ex_text = 'I am an example test text'
ex_word = cycle('coding')
rep_word = ''

while len(rep_word) < len(ex_text):
    rep_word += next(ex_word)

print(rep_word)
```

The code above will result in the following output:

```py
codingcodingcodingcodingc
```

You can also combine it with comprehensions and make your code more *Pythonic*:

```py
from itertools import cycle


phrase = 'I am an example test text'
word = cycle('coding')

rep_word = ''.join(next(word) for _ in phrase)

print(rep_word)
```

Which will also result in:

```py
codingcodingcodingcodingc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ex_text = "I am an example test text"
ex_word = "coding"
rep_word = ""

def find_spaces(str):
    for i, ltr in enumerate(str):
        if ltr == " ":
            yield i

full_word, part_word = divmod(len(ex_text), len(ex_word))
rep_word = ex_word * full_word + ex_word[:part_word]

spaces = find_spaces(ex_text)

for space_index in spaces:
    rep_word = rep_word[:space_index] + " " + rep_word[space_index:-1]

print(rep_word)
```